# My image appear on the codepen but not in my website in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to detect the userAgent. If you are using iPhone, then this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcKF1.png) appear. I test my result on Xcode iPhone Simulator. It works on my codepen like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nGBY.png) ,but when I put this web in ftp server and [link it](http://www.komistudio.com/www/). The [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlKa7.png) just not work on my simulator.

So I try to make the rule simple. If you are using Safari, then you can see the image. Basically let anyone can get in the if{}. But still, it work on codepen, not in my website. The result is same as on computer. Here is my html and js.

```js
/* global document */
alert(navigator.userAgent);
var isTrue = navigator.userAgent.match("Safari");
if(isTrue) {
   var image = document.createElement('img');
  image.setAttribute('src', 'https://i.imgur.com/VvrMpvU.png');
  document.querySelectorAll('.AddImageInhere').forEach((el) => {el.appendChild(image.cloneNode(true));});
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>KOMISTUDIO WEBAR</title>
<link href="css/simpleGridTemplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js/demo.js"></script>   
</head>
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="thumbnail"> <a href="#"><img src="images/icon01.jpg" alt="" width="2000" class="cards"/></a>
      <h4>TITLE</h4>
       <a href="sofa.usdz" rel="ar" class="AddImageInhere" ></a>
      <p class="tag">HTML, CSS, JS, WordPress</p>
      <p class="text_column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It also work on Code Snippet if change rule to "Safari",so maybe the problem it's inside the if{}.

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/abcd9597938/pen/bGGVmXV) and my [web](http://www.komistudio.com/www/)

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the document is not completely loaded when executing the js functions, document.querySelectorAll('.AddImageInhere') gives empty array.

Call the function after the document is ready.

Comment: How do I know when the document is ready? I'm new to javascript...

Comment: Okay, now I move <script></script> before </body> . Call my javascript later, and it work . Thank you ! But I still very curious how do you find it..

Comment: There is **Developer Tools** for the browser. Just need to press F12 to open it. There you can debug your code. Check youtube for video tutorials.